# ffmpeg using the same complex filter for multiple outputs

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube

Hello I am trying to use ffmpeg to live stream content to youtube as well as output an mp4. The issue is I have a complex filter and do not know how to apply it to both outputs.

Here is the code

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" 
-i ./public/images/ACE.png 
-i ./public/images/logo2.jpg 
-filter_complex "[1]scale=40:40[ovrl1], [v0][ovrl1] overlay=580:10:enable='between(t,1,5)'[v1];[2]scale=40:40[ovrl2], [v1][ovrl2] overlay=580:10:enable='between(t,5,15)'[v2];[v2] drawtext=fontfile=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf: \text='VideoGami':fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/1.05: enable='between(t,1,10)'" 
-acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/moo" 
-acodec aac -vcodec libx264 trial.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [tee muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1). Untested example:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" -i ./public/images/ACE.png -i ./public/images/logo2.jpg -filter_complex "[1]scale=40:40[ovrl1], [0:v:6][ovrl1] overlay=580:10:enable='between(t,1,5)'[v1];[2]scale=40:40[ovrl2], [v1][ovrl2] overlay=580:10:enable='between(t,5,15)',drawtext=fontfile=fontfile=/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf: \text='VideoGami':fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/1.05: enable='between(t,1,10)'[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a:6 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/moo|trial.mp4"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I am getting this error

[flv @ 0x7fe6590ff800] at most one audio stream is supported in flv

[tee @ 0x7fe658814000] Slave '[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/moo': error writing header: Invalid argument

[tee @ 0x7fe658814000] Slave muxer #0 failed, aborting.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

Error initializing output stream 0:0 --

Comment: @Ricky Provide a pastebin link containing your command and the complete console output.

Comment: Just tried it but once the encoding starts it breaks and gives a broken pipe message. Here is the pastebin link with the full console output  https://pastebin.com/d9meqAyv

Comment: @Ricky Going on a trip soon, so I won't be able to look at this for maybe 14 days. I recommend asking the ffmpeg-user mailing list.